# PHP Namespace Issues with Traits

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5.1, traits

I'm having the strangest problem today, where something that always works has somehow stopped working. Odds are, it's one of those stupid simple issues that I'm too blind to see.

So here's what's going on:

I have the following file structure (I'm only showing relevant files)

```
~/project
 v app
   v Models
        User.php
   v Support
     v Traits
        Sluggable.php
   composer.json
   composer.lock
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use App\Support\Traits\Sluggable;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    //////////////
    //* Traits *//
    //////////////
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, Sluggable;

    ////////////////////////
    //* Model Attributes *//
    ////////////////////////
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    /////////////////////
    //* Boot Override *//
    /////////////////////
    /**
     * Override the Boot Method to schedule tasks that are Event-Triggered.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        // Call the Parent Method
        parent::boot();

        // Intercept the 'Created' Event
        static::creating(function($user)
        {
            // Assign a Validation Token
            $user->validation_token = str_slug(str_random(64));

            // Initialize the Slug for the User
            $user->slug = $user->makeSlug();
        });
    }

    ////////////////////////////
    //* Attributes Overrides *//
    ////////////////////////////
    /**
     * Overrides the $user->name Attibute to update the Sluggable Name.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setNameAttribute($name)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $name;

        $this->attributes['slug'] = $this->makeSlug();
    }
}
```

**Traits.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Support\Traits;

trait Sluggable
{
    /**
     * The Name of the Attribute that determines the Slug.
     *
     * Use $this->$sluggableAttribute to determine the Sluggable Value.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $sluggableAttribute = 'name';

    /**
     * The Name of the Attribute that contains the Slug.
     *
     * Use $this->$slugAttribute to determine the Slug Value.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $slugAttribute = 'slug';

    /**
     * Generates a Slug based on the Sluggable Attribute.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function makeSlug()
    {
        // Intialize the Slug
        $this->$slugAttribute = str_slug($this->$sluggableAttribute);

        // Check for an existing Slug
        $slug = $this->whereRaw("{$this->slugAttribute} RLIKE '^{$this->$sluggableAttribute}(-[0-9]+)?$'")
            ->latest($timestamps ? UPDATED_AT : $this->primaryKey) // Find the Latest Slug
            ->pluck($this->slugAttribute); // Only grab the Slug Attribute

        // See if a Slug was Found
        if($slug)
        {
            // Determine the new Slug Identifier
            $slugID = intval(end(explode('-', $slug))) + 1;

            // Reassign a new Slug
            $this->$slugAttribute .= '-' . $slugID;
        }

        return $this->$slugAttribute;
    }
}
```

And I end up getting the error:

```
FatalErrorException in User.php line 19:
Trait 'App\Support\Traits\Sluggable' not found
```

And I have no idea why.

---

If it matters, I'm using Laravel 5.1 as my Framework.

**Edit:**

Here's the **composer.json** file, in case that matters:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "illuminate/html": "^5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/route.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste autoload section from your composer.json?

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Added the `composer.json` file. Also, running `composer dump-autoload` didn't work (Although I wish it had! :(  )

Comment: Pardon the question but... you do have the opening php tag in your Sluggable.php, right? :)

Comment: I do. Good guess though.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any space in directory/filename for example in `Support` , `Traits` or `Sluggable.php` at the beginning or at the end? You can create directory or filename with space and in editor you might not see any difference

Comment: When I checked this, I found the problem. It wasn't what you suggested, but it was a stupid issue, like I said. In short, **Sluggable.php** didn't actually have the **.php** extension. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

After further analysis, I found the issue, and was definitely one of those stupid simple issues that I'm was too blind to see.

Simply put, the **Sluggable.php** file lacked the **.php** extension. I guess I'm just so used to see file names without their extensions that I didn't notice.